# Error when compiling Caffe on OSX 10.12.1

Tags: macos, opencv, build, caffe

I followed the instruction [here](https://gist.github.com/doctorpangloss/f8463bddce2a91b949639522ea1dcbe4) and the file compilation is fine. But when it gets into the linker stage, I got the following error:

```
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
ld: library not found for -lopencv_core
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

I searched online but found nothing about this issue
Can anyone help me out?

I installed opencv3 in addition to opencv using `brew install --HEAD opencv3`

You can find my Makefile.config in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/75iHQhXG9To) post.
Thanks in advance!